# how to I flip sign while creating view from tables

Tags: sql, oracle

-I have data in two separate tables and while extracting data I need to add condition to flip the sign, the way we have setup is to extract data into a column and flipping the sign on data but I don't want the additional column. Condition to flip the sign is when the Account Name starts with A3/A4/A5. Can you please help me to create that additional condition to flip the sign.

[image]

```
Account Type   Flip Sign   Condition
-----------    ---------   ---------    
Liabilities           -1   A3   
Equity                -1   A4   
Revenue               -1   A5   
Assets                 1   A0   

Table1

Account_Name    Account_ID  
-------------   ----------  
A530003001001          235      
A331300002003          468      
A080001001000          255      
A293001004189          128      

Table2  

Account_ID      Balance 
----------  ----------- 
235               14700     
468               23500     
255          -226183.11     
128           130471.19
```

Expected View

```
Account             Value
-------------   ---------   
A530003001001      -14700       
A331300002003      -23500       
A080001001000  -226183.11       
A293001004189   130471.19
```

Comment: Aren't you missing account type in Table1?

Comment: first table is just for the reference how the flip should work

Comment: You are making no sense. The view should take the values from Table2 and either flip them or not, depending on account type. But the account type is not present in Table1. So how do you decide which amounts to flip and which not to flip?

Comment: Wait - does "CONDITION" in the first table really mean the first two characters of the Account_Name? Does the Account Name actually also encode the account **type**? If so, you need more information: what is **A2**? It is present in the last line of Table1 but it is not present in the "flipping" table. (Also this is a **terrible** data model, where the account name encodes the account type - but that is a different issue.)

Comment: when the Account Name starts with A3/A4/A5 those accounts I need to flip the sign, from table 1 there are two such accounts that I need to flip and the other two accounts value I should be able to extract as is, may be I am not clear when I added just A3 hope this is clear now

Comment: In your images you have a **\*** symbol in some of the values in the flipping table - what's with those? Do you mean "multiplication sign"? But then why do you have them in the CONDITION column (but not in all the values)?

Comment: yes, it is clear now but you should add that to your original post (that the flipping is controlled by the first two characters of the account name) - and you must also include A2 in the "flipping" table.

Comment: you can ignore the * symbol

Comment: The real answer here is: Store everything as positive and handle the debit and credit logic as part of your transactions. All of this other stuff is an exercise in futility that will come back to bite you later.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (not tested since no `CREATE TABLE/INSERT` statements were provided):

```
create view view_1 as 
select t1.account_name, f.flip_sign * t2.balance as value
from   table1 t1 join flipping_table f  on substr(t1.account_name, 2) =  f.condition
                 join table2         t2 on t1.account_id              = t2.account_id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are columns Account_Type, Flip_Sign, and Condition on the same table as columns Account_Name and Account_ID. If it is, then you may use the following query.

```
SELECT t1.Account_Name AS Account,
       t2.Balance * t1.Flip_sign AS Value
  FROM Table1 t1
 INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.Account_ID = t2.Account_ID
```